# Changes in Page/Dirty Page Backbone/MarioneteJS

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have the following question:
I have an application that I'm writing with Backbone/MarioneteJS, and I have the following issue, maybe is a simple and I'm complicating the issue.
In the application you can edit some fields and then save them, I want to be available that when the user edit some filed and he tries to navigate to another place, the application will block/inform him that he have unsaved changes.
In the past not in Backbone/MarioneteJS, we use a global variable that I checked before leaving to another place, something like(pseudocode like):

```
var dirtyPage = false;
// when editing we do
if (editing) {
    dirtPage = true;
}
// In another part of the code before navigating to another place
if (dirtPage) {
     ShowMessage("Unsaved Changes");
} else {
     Navigate(AnotherPlace);
}
```

I know that if I do it like below it will work, but maybe there is a more elegant way to resolve the issue.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using backbone model to help you track all of these?  Read the great backbone fundamentals in here https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I understand your answer, you mean that after a change is done, I can check if the model was changed rigth?, but I want to have this cross over the application and not checking every model, I want to have in all the places in the application and not start checking for every model, is this whhat you meant or I miss something, thanks again